# Source command with extend parameter

Tags: shell

I saw some commands like `source filename --extend`.
I search the web and find nothing with it.
What does "extend" parameter mean?
Thanks.

Comment: You can have a look at the manual via "man source" to see all the options.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what `help source` says for bash:

> If any ARGUMENTS are supplied, they become the positional parameters
> when FILENAME is executed.

In other words `--extend` is a feature implemented by filename which you have not told us anything about.